# Can I disable DC Universe Online's accept licence terms?

Tags: ps3, dc-universe-online

Every time I start up DC Universe Online, it requires me to scroll through and accept the license terms - even when they haven't changed since I last played the game. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: I've seen this also in several other games. Not sure then there's a way to disable this. As I don't own this one, I won't "answer" but I doubt there is something you can do.

Comment: @TZHJX Not to be obvious, but have you tried asking in the [official PS3 forums](http://forums.station.sony.com/dcuops3/forums/list.m)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a [topic on the DC Universe PS3 forums](http://forums.station.sony.com/dcuops3/posts/list.m?&topic_id=12134), this was a known bug with no obvious cause. Many people only had to accept the terms once (and again with new patches) and others had to accept them every single time the game launched. There was no clear distinction between users who saw the bug and those who did not.

Those who were experiencing the problem reported it fixed sometime around February 12th (shortly after this question was asked). This date doesn't correlate with an update to the game, so it's possible it was a server issue that the DC Universe team fixed outside of the standard patch cycle.

Considering the inability to access and modify game config files on the PS3 (unlike standard PC games), it seems unlikely that you would have been able to disable this behavior altogether. If this was in fact a server issue as speculated, it would most likely prevent you from playing the game if the terms were not accepted.